# About the Comment system in New Review BETA feature

Tags: discussion, comments, review-beta

Review system looks good in controlling spam and low quality contents  . I am aware it is still in BETA.

While reviewing i came across an answer whose author had less Reps to comment originally , hence seems to have posted it as answer . Thus reviewing enables me to post comment below it as ,

`This is really a comment, not an answer to the question. Please use "add comment" to leave feedback for the author.`

But it seems meaningless to post it under such answers whose Author have less rep . So i found a comment by [izx](https://askubuntu.com/users/58612/izx) more useful for such situation as

> This is really a comment, not an answer to the question. You can
>   always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient
>   [reputation](https://askubuntu.com/faq#reputation) you will be able to
>   [comment on any post](https://askubuntu.com/privileges/comment).

So should we leave the post as `Not sure` or wait for OP to gain rep to comment so.

Or the BETA system is not yet to be discussed until fully integrated.

PLUS, what to do for the answers such as [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5790/gnome-do-in-doesnt-have-the-docky-appearance-anymore), whose author seems not to exist on AU any more.

[image: Author without account]

Comment: I guess Moderators just changed it , seems good. Thanks.

Comment: I had some questions about the new review Beta feature and found many of my answers here http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/review?sort=newest. That said there is a lot of material to get through.

Comment: Thanks a lot , i will go through it.